# Proving $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've done a limit comparison test that relies on $$\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$$ which seems to be true for $x > 0$, but I'd like to prove it before letting my solution rely on it.

I've tried a few different things that led nowhere. Never faced a problem like this so I'm really not sure what's on the plate for strategies. (I'm in Calc 2.)

Thanks for any advice or nudges in the right direction!

Comment: It seems to me that how you approach this depends on how you define arctan. All of the answers, at this point, use the fact that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arctan(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$.  One might use the trigonometric definition which defines tangent as the ratio of two sides of a right triangle. Some also use the series $\arctan(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$. What is the definition you are using?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, $\arctan(x)<x$ for all $x>0$ (and you can apply this to $1/x$ to get your inequality).

Indeed $f:x \mapsto x-\arctan(x)$ is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ and
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x^2} >0$$

so $f$ is strictly increasing. And $f(0)=0$, so $f(x) > 0$ for all $x >0$. So $x > \arctan(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You may like this method:
$$ \arctan(\frac1x)=\int_0^{\frac1x}\frac1{1+t^2}dt\le\int_0^{\frac1x}dt=\frac1x. $$

Answer (score 0):

We put $f(x) =arct(\frac{1}{x}) - \frac{1}{x} $
f is derivable at $\mathbb{R^{+*}} $

$f'(x) =\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\frac{1}{x^2} =\frac{1}{x^2}(1-\frac{1}{1+x^2})  =\frac{1}{1+x^2}>0 $

So :

$(*) f(x)$ is an incremental function at $\mathbb{R^+}  $

$(**) \lim _{x \to 0^+} f(x) =-\infty$

$(***) \lim _{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$

After $(*) $ and $(**) $ and $(***) $  we can see

$f(x) = arct(\frac{1}{x}) - \frac{1}{x}  <0$

Finally :

$\forall x>0 $    $ arct(\frac{1}{x}) < \frac{1}{x}$